# Get tables from schema

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have one database named dev. Inside it I have schema named `test_spect`. The schema consists of some tables. The `test_spect` is not public. How to get the table name and its data from `test_spect`. When I run

```
\dt test_spect.*
```

It says

```
No matching relations found.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with a query on the system tables?

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind <> 'i' AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
--## change here your schema    
    AND nspname = 'public'
--##
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC;
```

**EDIT**

The same query without the pg_total_relation_size function:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation"
FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind = 'r' AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
    AND nspname = 'public'
  ORDER BY relname
```

Comment: It says, ERROR:  function pg_total_relation_size(oid) does not exist

Comment: that's curious.. which postgres version are you using?

Comment: try removing the line `pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"` from my previous query and tell me what you got

Comment: This query here works on 9.5, 9.6 and 10. `SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation"
FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind = 'r' AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
    AND nspname = 'public'
  ORDER BY relname`

Comment: It says ERROR:  function pg_total_relation_size(oid) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to ad
d explicit type casts.

Comment: OKay Now I got this
 relation
----------
(0 rows)

Comment: I just edited my answer with a smaller query. Change the **public** parameter with your schema (test_spect?)

Comment: I'm runnning SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation" FROM pg_class C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace) WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND C.relkind = 'r' AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast' AND nspname = 'test_spect' ORDER BY relname;

Comment: If it gives you nothing, it might be you have no tables in this schema.. which according to you is not true. Try this one (without the table filter) `SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation" FROM pg_class C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace) WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast' AND nspname = 'public' ORDER BY relname;`

Comment: Still No luck for test_spect if it is public it shows something... i think i need to grant access as public

Comment: It might indeed help :D Let me know how it went... now I'm really curious :)

Comment: Thank you for your replies and time, i will reply if i got some work around on this. Thank you

Comment: The OP tagged the question as `AMAZON-REDSHIFT`, which is based on postgres V8.   Specifically, Redshift does not support Database Object-Size functions, as per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default you're in the public schema. You need to navigate to your schema using

```
set SEARCH_PATH to test_spect;
```

try `\d` after that.

Comment: it says, ERROR:  External schema "test_spect" cannot be set in search_path

Comment: Are you using amazon redshift?

Comment: Yes i am using Reshift, How to get tables